# php-fpm not creating socket

Tags: php, apache

I'm setting up a WordPress website using Apache and php7.4-fpm.

I'm aware that the most common misconfiguration in this combination is a mismatch between the socket definition in the configuration files of both httpd and php-fpm.

I've created both configurations and restarted both services.
After restarting both services, attempts to load the website fail. The logs indicate that the socket can't be reached. When I check the filesystem, I can see that the socket hasn't been created.

This is the vhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.localdev
        Servername mysite.localdev


        <Directory /var/www/mysite.localdev>
                AllowOverride none
                FallbackResource /index.php
                Require all granted
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        </Directory>

        #ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/mysite.localdev/$1                                                         
        ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/var/run/php/mysite.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/mysite.localdev
        DirectoryIndex index.php /index.php


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.localdev.error-log


        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,                                                                          
        # alert, emerg.                                                                                                                             
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.localdev.access-log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

and this is the pool configuration

```
[mysite]

user = mantis
group = mantis


listen = /var/run/php/mysite.sock


listen.owner = mantis
listen.group = mantis


pm = dynamic

pm.max_children = 5


pm.start_servers = 2

pm.min_spare_servers = 1

pm.max_spare_servers = 3


php_admin_value[post_max_size]  = 5G
php_admin_value[upload_max_filesize]  = 5G
```

What could be preventing php from creating the socket?

Comment: If I remember correctly I had a problem with permissions to the pid and sock directories. Who is the owner of /var/run/php and what permissions are set on the directory? By the way, the location of the pid file might be different. Check php-fpm.conf for that.

Comment: /var/run/php is owned by www-data. It is populated by socket files. Most of the socket files are owned by the user who also owns the file system respective docroots of websites currently running on this system.